# NodeJS and MySQL Promise: Why am I getting ReferenceError: DataBase is not defined?

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise, node-mysql, nodejs-server

I'm just learning to use promises for MySQL in NodeJS. I'm using the following code to wrap my MySQL queries in Promises.

```
const mysql = require( 'mysql' );

let config = {
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'myuser',
    password : 'mypassword',
    database: 'mydatabase'
};

class Database {
    constructor( config ) {
        this.connection = mysql.createConnection( config );
    }
    query( sql, args ) {
        return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
            this.database.query( sql, args, ( err, rows ) => {
                if ( err )
                    return reject( err );
                resolve( rows );
            } );
        } );
    }
    close() {
        return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
            this.connection.end( err => {
                if ( err )
                    return reject( err );
                resolve();
            } );
        } );
    }
}

let mydb = new DataBase(config);
```

But I'm getting the following error in my console;

```
let mydb = new DataBase;
           ^
ReferenceError: DataBase is not defined
```

I've tried using both uppercase and lowercase for DataBase. I've tried with and without new. But I don't understand why I'm getting this error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You spelled it as `Database`. It just needs to match the exact spelling.

Comment: Doh! Thanks. If you list it as the answer I'll select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spelling just needs to match. Right now you have `Database` and `DataBase`

Answer (score 2):

Because the class name is **Database** and not **DataBase**